# Special Products Collection

Tags: magento2, product-collection

I've been trying to get a special price collection of products for Magento 2 but I keep on failing.

I've got the following example that works(almost):

```
    protected function _getSaleCategoryCollection()
    {
        if ($this->_productCollection === null) {
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection */
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $this->_catalogLayer->prepareProductCollection($collection);

            $todayStart = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(0, 0, 0)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $todayEnd = $this->_localeDate->date()->setTime(23, 59, 59)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $collection
                ->addStoreFilter()
                ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    'special_from_date',
                    [
                        'or' => [
                            ['date' => true, 'to' => $todayEnd],
                            ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'left'
                )->addAttributeToFilter(
                    'special_to_date',
                    [
                        'or' => [
                            ['date' => true, 'from' => $todayStart],
                            ['is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('null')]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'left'
                )->addAttributeToFilter(
                    [
                        ['attribute' => 'special_price', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')]
                    ]
                );





            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }

        return $this->_productCollection;
    }
}
```

Alright, so the above example shows me all the products that has the special price 'value' not empty and also if the product is between the 2 dates.

The problem comes when I have a product where the special price is not empty, but equal to the normal price(therefore the product does not have a special price).

So in conclusion I need to add an 'and' condition to the above collection so the `final price < smaller price`

I've added following after researching different forums:

```
...
 )->addAttributeToFilter(
                    [
                        ['attribute' => 'special_price', 'is' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('not null')]
                    ]
                );


            $collection->getSelect()->where(
                    'price_index.final_price < price_index.price'
            );


            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
....
```

After adding that `getSelect->where()` , I'm only getting 4 simple products so I'm thinking this is not the right approach for me.
Also, I'm using elasticsearch(I don't know if relevant).

I'd appreciate if anyone has an idea.
Thank you!

Comment: if the product doesn't have a special price why does it have the special price from/to dates set?

Comment: @paj I'm not really understanding your question. I'm simply filtering for products that have the special price not null and it fits between the dates.